# Could not find method android() for arguments ... on root project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been trying to import a project to Android Studio and this is where I am stuck, there is a similar question on Stack Overflow but it did not provide a solution to my particular error sadly...

This is my error log:

```
Error:(24, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_*********$_run_closure3@****] on root project 'project_name' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Here is my file Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
}
dependencies {
}
```

If you can help me, thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

Move this from the project `build.gradle` file to the module `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
}
dependencies {
}
```

Comment: I did this but unfortunately it does not work: /
Screen : https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ICPEGULolRc/WZw6JMy12II/AAAAAAAADGY/E_L9eH5cKzEgrvCevLiU0LTpBz0vsUhYgCLcBGAs/s1600/Capture.PNG

Comment: @Alex: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it does not work" means. You might want to use Android Studio to create a new project, so you can see what the two `build.gradle` files should contain.

Comment: I moved this in gradle and I paste in the gradle:app :
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
}
dependencies {
}

but it does not work you can see the screen; if you can help me please

Comment: @Alex: This is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. There is something wrong with your `res/drawable/tagborder.xml` file. You may wish to consider asking a separate question, where you provide a [mcve]. That would include the `res/drawable/tagborder.xml` file and the error message that you are seeing.

Comment: Yes i understood, the first problem is solved, thank you, i will try to post another question about the new error
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
}
dependencies {
}
```

These belong to (Module:app) level of build.gradle

Comment: I did this but unfortunately it does not work: /
Screen : https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ICPEGULolRc/WZw6JMy12II/AAAAAAAADGY/E_L9eH5cKzEgrvCevLiU0LTpBz0vsUhYgCLcBGAs/s1600/Capture.PNG

Comment: After doing so clean project and then rebuild it.